# FB.getLoginStatus returns 'unknown' after FB.logout

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.logout() returns 'unknown' status on completion as well as a delayed FB.getLoginStatus() after 10 seconds. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? The console statements are printed so the angular functions are irrelevant.

```
if (angular.element(document.getElementById('logout-button')).scope().userDetails.facebookUser) {

    FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        setTimeout(function () {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response1) {
                console.log(response1);
                console.log("checking login status");
                angular.element(document.getElementById('logout-button')).scope().logout();
            })
        }, 10000)
    });

}
```

Comment: What does `console` print ? What it should print ?

Comment: Should be an object with status: disconnected or status:not_authorized in both console statements. Instead, they both print out status:unknown. The problem is I redirect the users back to the login page and the FB login button does not appear unless the user is logged out properly.

Comment: This driving me so nuts! Nothing new @PrajeethEmanuel ?

Comment: @manonthemoon status:not_authorized is only returned when the FB user has never authenticated your app. status:unknown is returned when the FB user has logged out of your application or FB. I solved this problem by creating a custom login button and calling FB.login() only if the user does not have an access token. A logout button on other pages calls FB.logout() which in turn deletes the access token of the user even if the status is unknown. Hope this helped! (I used the same method for google login. I believe they have a section for logging in using a custom button)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the browser stores the logged out session into cookies.
Use the following snippet in the callback of your logout method

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
    document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) {
        document.cookie = c.
            replace(/^ +/, "").
            replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";domain=localhost;path=/");
    });
});
```

Replace **`localhost`** with your domain name